# Configurar directorio test jest

Tags: reactjs, test, jest, jestjs

Estoy intentando configurar la ruta de test para mis test
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi jest.config.ts esta configurado asi y esta en el mismo nivel que test y src

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ['<rootDir>/tests/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-svg-transformer',
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
};
```

Recibo este error siempre

> No tests found, exiting with code 1 Run with `--passWithNoTests` to
> exit with code 0 No files found in
> C:\Desarrollo\grupoJalair\Telematica\RepoMiguel\telematics-menu. Make
> sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory. To set up
> Jest, make sure a package.json file exists. Jest Documentation:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration Files:
> "C:\Desarrollo\grupoJalair\Telematica\RepoMiguel\telematics-menu\tests\menu\ToggleArrow.test.tsx"
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Como puedo arreglar esto?